# Hiding HTML around Custom Field if empty with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to hide all the html if my custom fields are empty in Wordpress

I'm using this:

```
<?php if (the_field( 'attribute_1' ) & the_field( 'value_1' ) != "") { ?>
<li style="line-height:2.25em;border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc;"><p style="font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;"><?php the_field( 'attribute_1' ); ?> <span style="float:right;font-weight:600;font-family:'Varela Round';"><?php the_field( 'value_1' ); ?></span></p></li>
<?php } ?>
```

But only 1 custom field shows up, any ideas why? I've looked into it quite a bit but can't figure it out

Comment: What are the values of `the_field( 'attribute_1' )` and `the_field( 'value_1' )`?  You should probably be using `&&`.

Comment: The values are just regular text, currently asdasd for attribute_1 and asd for attribute_2

when I use && only attribute_1 displays

Comment: You mean to use `&&` - that's correct.  Yours is not correct.

Comment: Ah yes, I do use &&. I'm sorry I'm tired I pasted wrong. So with &&, I only see 1 custom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**assuming** that your fields are correct (`attribute_1` and `value_1`), then the issue with the code is the use of the incorrect functions.

[the_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) **outputs** the contents of the field.

In your `if` condition, you need to use [get_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) which **returns** the contents of the field:

```
<?php if (get_field( 'attribute_1' ) && get_field( 'value_1' ) != "") { ?>
    <li style="line-height:2.25em;border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
        <p style="font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;"><?php the_field( 'attribute_1' ); ?> <span style="float:right;font-weight:600;font-family:'Varela Round';"><?php the_field( 'value_1' ); ?></span>
        </p>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you have no idea how happy you've made me, thanks for the help and the explanation. now i know for future reference! thanks thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided details about the methods listed above, you could try something like this.

```
<?php
if(isset("myfield") && isset("myfield2")){
   echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"customField1\"></input>";
} //repeat as necessary
?>
```

If you are banking on 'myfield' being variables from a different page, then you should use:

```
<?php //use $_GET if necessary
if(isset($_POST['myfield']) && isset($_POST['myfield2'])){
   echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"customField1\"></input>";
} //repeat as necessary
?>
```